Azure Storage Queue JavaScript TTL
The TTL isn't being set on messages added to the queue using this code, and I can't fathom why that might be, even after trying multiple different iterations. Stack Overflow wants me to add more details, but it's a pretty succinct problem.


// Function to send a message to the queue with a TTL
const sendToQueue = async (messageContent, ttlInSeconds) => {
    const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    const queueServiceClient = new QueueServiceClient(
        `https://${storageAccountName}.queue.core.windows.net`,
        credential
    );

    const queueClient = queueServiceClient.getQueueClient(queueName);
    const message = JSON.stringify({ message: messageContent });

    // Set the time-to-live (TTL) for the message (in seconds)
    const options = {
        timeToLive: ttlInSeconds // TTL is in seconds
    };

    await queueClient.sendMessage(message, options);
};

app.http('alert', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        console.log("JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        const messageContent = request.query.get("message"); // Get the 'message' parameter from URL

        if (messageContent) {
            try {
                // Your message sending logic here
                const ttlInSeconds = 3600; // Set TTL to 1 hour (adjust as needed)
                const result = await sendToQueue(messageContent, ttlInSeconds); // Pass TTL in seconds

                return {
                    status: 200,
                    body: "Message added to the queue successfully.",
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error adding message to the queue:", error);
                return {
                    status: 500,
                    body: "Internal server error.",
                };
            }
        } else {
            return {
                status: 400,
                body: "Please pass a 'message' parameter in the URL.",
            };
        }
    }
});




I believe you are not able to set the message TTL is because you are using incorrect property name. The correct property name is messageTimeToLive based on the documentation available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/storage-queue/queuesendmessageoptions?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-queue-queuesendmessageoptions-messagetimetolive.
Please try with the following code:
const sendToQueue = async (messageContent, ttlInSeconds) => {
    const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    const queueServiceClient = new QueueServiceClient(
        `https://${storageAccountName}.queue.core.windows.net`,
        credential
    );

    const queueClient = queueServiceClient.getQueueClient(queueName);
    const message = JSON.stringify({ message: messageContent });

    // Set the time-to-live (TTL) for the message (in seconds)
    const options = {
        messageTimeToLive: ttlInSeconds // TTL is in seconds
    };

    await queueClient.sendMessage(message, options);
};


Sadly the same outcome, the expiration doesn't match the TTL provided.

Can you share the output of what you are seeing?

As in, what I see in the queue once it's posted?

That’s correct. If the TTL is not set, the default will be 7 days. Do you see that for message expiry?

Yeah, it's always 7 days, no matter what I try.

Got it. :)


// Function to send a message to the queue with a TTL of 10 seconds
const sendToQueue = async (messageContent, ttlInSeconds) => {
    const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    const queueServiceClient = new QueueServiceClient(
        `https://${storageAccountName}.queue.core.windows.net`,
        credential
    );

    const queueClient = queueServiceClient.getQueueClient(queueName);
    const message = JSON.stringify({ message: messageContent });

    // Set the time-to-live (TTL) for the message (in seconds)
    const options = {
        messageTimeToLive: Number(ttlInSeconds) // TTL is in seconds
    };

    await queueClient.sendMessage(message, options);
};





app.http('alert', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        console.log("JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        const messageContent = request.query.get("message"); // Get the 'message' parameter from URL

        if (messageContent) {
            try {

                ttlInSeconds = 3600
                // Your message sending logic here
                const result = await sendToQueue(messageContent, ttlInSeconds);

                return {
                    status: 200,
                    body: "Message added to the queue successfully.",
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error adding message to the queue:", error);
                return {
                    status: 500,
                    body: "Internal server error.",
                };
            }
        } else {
            return {
                status: 400,
                body: "Please pass a 'message' parameter in the URL.",
            };
        }
    }
});



